# Stop Game auto starting Xcode spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I have written a game in Xcode in the myscene.m file. I have a problem however. When ever the game loads for testing or is opened the game automatically starts. Is there any code that I can implement to only start the game when the screen in touched?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a method when the screen is touched:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self startMyGame];
}

-(void)startMyGame
{
    // add your game start code here...
}
```

You should really think about your code logic. Usually a menu screen is run before the game is actually started. Menu options such as "start game" give the user a clear choice as to start the game when they are ready. Food for thought...

Comment: The problem I am getting is as soon as I click play game on the intro view it jumps straight into the game without allowing the user to then touch the screen to begin the actual game play. If i remove the intro screen altogether and open the app the game just starts without and input from the user.